# Queries from background worker conflict?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Is there a problem if I execute queries from multiple threads using the same ConnectionString? What happens if two or more threads try to send data at the same time?

```
string globalConnectionString = @"some_stringHere!";

//create new backgroundWorker if new logFile is created (txt file).
// ....
    
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   // get some data from created logFile
   string serialNumber = getSerialNumber(logFile);
   string testResult = getTestResult(logFile);
       
   // if server is online, send data
   if(serverIsOnline)
   {
      using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnecton(globalConnectionString))
      {
         SqlCommand someCommand = new SqlCommand("some insert/update command here!", connection);
         connection.Open();
         Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual issue?

Comment: Don't use a BGW to begin with. It's obsolete since 2012 when `async/await` were introduced. You can replace the BGW with `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`

Comment: Your `SqlConnection` is wrapped in a `using` *statement* and creates a new instance every time the `method` is called, this is the same for `SqlCommand`.

Additionally, a *database* is designed to deal with many *concurrent* connections and all the above is designed to *connection pool* as necessary. There is no classic *thread safety* issue here as such, however databases are not immune from data races (which is a different topic all together)... 

On saying that, anything else you do in this method may not be,.. for instance, `getSerialNumber`, `getTestResult`

Comment: There *is* a problem if. you use BGW - your code becomes overly complicated, coordinating multiple asynchronous calls becomes hard, while executing them in sequence becomes simply impossible. There's no problem with executing asynchronous commands *using the same connection* as long as they're executed sequentially, ie `await cmd1.Execute..Async(); await cmd.Execute...Async();`. There's no problem with opening multiple connections concurrently and have each one execute commands, but there may be performance issues, as each connection acquires its own locks and could block other connections

Comment: Why do you ask this question? Databases have no problem with concurrent connections (except SQLite). On the other hand, if you want to make a slow query go faster by executing it multiple times in parallel, you'll probably increase delays rather than reduce them. All queries are sent through the same network card, served by the same server, same CPUs, same disks etc. Many databases parallelize query processing too. Most of the time improving the query is far better (and easier) than trying to parallelize them from the client

Answer (score 4):

**Concurrent connections are OK, if used correctly**

There's no problem with using multiple connections concurrently, assuming it's done for the right reason. Databases can handle thousands of concurrent client connections.

Executing the same slow query in parallel to make it finish faster will probably make it *even slower* as each connection may block the others. Many databases parallelize query processing already, producing far better results than crude client-side parallelism.

If you want to make a slow query go faster, you'd get better results by investigating why it's slow and fixing the perf issues. For example, if you want to insert 10K rows, it's faster to use eg SqlBulkCopy or `BULK INSERT` to load the rows than executing 10K INSERTs that will end up blocking each other for access to the same table and even data pages

You can use the same connection to execute asynchronous queries (eg with `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`, `ExecuteReaderAsync()` etc, provided they execute one after the other. You can't execute multiple concurrent queries on the same connection, at least not without going through some hoops.

**The real problem**

The real problem is using a BackgroundWorker in the first place. That class is obsolete since 2012 when `async/await` were introduced. With BGW it's extremely hard to combine multiple asynchronous operations. Progress reporting is available through the `Progress<T>` class and cooperative cancellation through `CancellationTokenSource`. Check [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) for a detailed explanation.

You can replace the BGW calls in your code with only `await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()`. You could create an asynchronous method to perform insert the data into the database :

```
private async Task InsertTestData(string serialNumber,string testResult)
{
   // if server is online, send data
   if(serverIsOnline)
   {
      using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnecton(globalConnectionString))
      {
         var someCommand = new SqlCommand("some insert/update command here!", connection);
         someCommand.Parameters.Add("@serial",SqlDbType.NVarChar,30).Value=serialNumber;
         ...
         connection.Open();
         Command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
      }
   }
}
```

If retrieving the serial number and test data is time consuming, you can use `Task.Run` to run each of them in the background :

```
   string serialNumber = await Task.Run(()=>getSerialNumber(logFile));
   string testResult = await Task.Run(()=>getTestResult(logFile));
   await InsertTestData(serialNumber,testResult);
```

You could also use a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to simplify the database :

```
private async Task InsertTestData(string serialNumber,string testResult)
{
   // if server is online, send data
   if(serverIsOnline)
   {
      using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnecton(globalConnectionString))
      {
         await connection.ExecuteAsync("INSERT .... VALUES(@serial,@test)",
                               new {serial=serialNumber,test=testResults});
      }
   }
}
```

Dapper will generate a parameterized query and match the parameters in the query with properties in the anonymous object by name.

Comment: Ill upvote, you put 10 times more effort into this than i would have, and should completely answer the problem and more

Comment: @MichaelRandall if you consider how often such questions appear, it's just a matter of writing the same answer again, modified to match the question. On the other hand, we're still missing *why* the question was asked. Is it a general question, or is the OP trying to improve the perf of a slow batch insert or update? Each case requires a different (but also common) answer.

Comment: thnks for very good answer!!, i'm using backgroundWorker because industrial machines are WinXP framework 4.0. Machine performs electrical component test to PCB boards, when test finish, it creates txt files with test results (one txt-file per PCB). To avoid GUI blocking while serialNumber and testResult are calculated from each txt-files i decided to use multi-threading..

Comment: You can use  `async/await` if you add the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package. There's no `Execute...Async`, there are `BeginExecute` and `EndExecute` methods that can be adapted to tasks with [Task.FromAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=netframework-4.5.2). Even without `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` you can use tasks. You'll have to use `ContinueWith` to handle the continuation and execute the next command, or get back to the UI thread

Comment: interesant..  i'll check it... goin back to question, there is not problem if new connection/query is made on every new bkgroundworker right ? thnks!

Comment: i'll add `while(bkgroundWorker.isBusy) Thread.Sleep(100);`  before new worker creation to ensure hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Reading the connection string isn't an issue here. You would have a problem if you would share the SqlConnection object through multiple threads. But that's not the case in your code.

Comment: Yes, think same. It's a new system at my work and I don't want to break something hahaha thnks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a question about `Isolation` from [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Isolation) properties. Please have a look at them.

Based on the SQL standard a single SQL query operates on a steady (consistent) state of the table(s) which the query works on. So this definition dictates that, it can NOT see any changes while it's being executed. However, as far as I know not all DBMS software follow this rule perfectly. For example there are products and / or Isolation levels that allow dirty reads.

Here is very detailed [explanation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/240886) from another user.